# MS Word 16+ VBA Index - Insert TABS

Tags: vba, indexing, ms-word

Creating an index to break out acronyms - am trying to get

TLA  [tab]  Three Letter Acronym.......5

acronym, tab, expanded version Page(s) for index.

But it won't let me add a tab. Updated the Index1 Style but still nothing.

[image: VBA Pasted tab in index doesn't show]

Comment: Use spaces instead, there's some controls that don't support extended character sets, such as new lines or in this case tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I can use Subcategories to help sort it out - SYNTAX MUST BE EXACT included spaces that tend to creep in...
{ XE "tBXP" } for the definition and
{ XE "tBXP:Template BIM-Execution Plan" } for the sub entry so the def shows under the sorted index

[image]

Unfortunately doesn't answer why I can't do this in the text in the entry!